azure load balancer backend pool workloads can't communicate to frontend pool
I am trying to setup some Highly Available (HA) workloads using Azure loadbalancer:

LB front end:

IP: 110.3.0.1, Port: 6443


LB backend:

VM1: 110.3.0.2, Port: 6443
VM2: 110.3.0.3, Port: 6443
VM3: 110.3.0.4, Port: 6443



The loadbalancer is supposed to distribute the requests received on the front end to the backend. This would be through both external to loadbalancer and internal.
For example, if VM1 were to send a self-request to the service it would send the request to the frontend IP instead of to itself (VM1) or to other nodes (VM2, VM3).
I can't get this setup to work as there is no connectivity (connection timeout) from any of the backend pool IPs to the front end.
Is this expected?
Here's the LB config (in JSON view):
{
  "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
  "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test",
  "name": "mylb-test",
  "type": "microsoft.network/loadbalancers",
  "sku": {
      "name": "Standard",
      "tier": "Regional"
  },
  "location": "myregion",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
      "resourceGuid": "resourceGuid",
      "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
              "name": "mylb-test-FE01",
              "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/frontendIPConfigurations/mylb-test-FE01",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIPConfigurations",
              "properties": {
                  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                  "privateIPAddress": "110.3.0.1",
                  "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                  "subnet": {
                      "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myvnet/subnets/mysubnet"
                  },
                  "loadBalancingRules": [
                      {
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/loadBalancingRules/mylb-test-RULE01"
                      }
                  ],
                  "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
              },
              "zones": [
                  "1",
                  "2",
                  "3"
              ]
          }
      ],
      "backendAddressPools": [
          {
              "name": "mylb-test-BE01-",
              "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/backendAddressPools/mylb-test-BE01-",
              "properties": {
                  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                  "loadBalancerBackendAddresses": [
                      {
                          "name": "be01",
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/backendAddressPools/mylb-test-BE01-/loadBalancerBackendAddresses/be01",
                          "properties": {
                              "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                              "ipAddress": "110.3.0.2",
                              "virtualNetwork": {
                                  "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myvnet"
                              }
                          },
                          "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools/loadBalancerBackendAddresses"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "be02",
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/backendAddressPools/mylb-test-BE01-/loadBalancerBackendAddresses/be02",
                          "properties": {
                              "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                              "ipAddress": "110.3.0.3",
                              "virtualNetwork": {
                                  "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myvnet"
                              }
                          },
                          "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools/loadBalancerBackendAddresses"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "be03",
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/backendAddressPools/mylb-test-BE01-/loadBalancerBackendAddresses/be03",
                          "properties": {
                              "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                              "ipAddress": "110.3.0.4",
                              "virtualNetwork": {
                                  "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myvnet"
                              }
                          },
                          "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools/loadBalancerBackendAddresses"
                      }
                  ],
                  "loadBalancingRules": [
                      {
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/loadBalancingRules/mylb-test-RULE01"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools"
          }
      ],
      "loadBalancingRules": [
          {
              "name": "mylb-test-RULE01",
              "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/loadBalancingRules/mylb-test-RULE01",
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/loadBalancingRules",
              "properties": {
                  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                  "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                      "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/frontendIPConfigurations/mylb-test-FE01"
                  },
                  "frontendPort": 6443,
                  "backendPort": 6443,
                  "enableFloatingIP": false,
                  "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
                  "protocol": "Tcp",
                  "enableDestinationServiceEndpoint": false,
                  "enableTcpReset": false,
                  "allowBackendPortConflict": false,
                  "loadDistribution": "SourceIP",
                  "disableOutboundSnat": true,
                  "backendAddressPool": {
                      "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/backendAddressPools/mylb-test-BE01-"
                  },
                  "backendAddressPools": [
                      {
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/backendAddressPools/mylb-test-BE01-"
                      }
                  ],
                  "probe": {
                      "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/probes/mylb-test-HR01"
                  }
              }
          }
      ],
      "probes": [
          {
              "name": "mylb-test-HR01",
              "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/probes/mylb-test-HR01",
              "properties": {
                  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                  "protocol": "Tcp",
                  "port": 6443,
                  "intervalInSeconds": 20,
                  "numberOfProbes": 1,
                  "probeThreshold": 1,
                  "loadBalancingRules": [
                      {
                          "id": "/subscriptions/mysubcriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/mylb-test/loadBalancingRules/mylb-test-RULE01"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/probes"
          }
      ],
      "inboundNatRules": [],
      "outboundRules": [],
      "inboundNatPools": []
  }
}

PS: this is for a self managed Kubernetes cluster to have K8s master nodes initial setup to use the LB frontend IP as the control-plane-endpoint (based on doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)

Since the post is not about programming, it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It might be on topic for [sf] or DevOps.
